# SQL request: REPLACE and wildcard %. How to do the right thing?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, replace, wildcard, mysql-5.7

MySQL 5.7 database has `wp_post` table in which the `post_content` column is located. The `post_content` column contains HTML code (WordPress blog posts) in which there are text and different links.
I need to build a SQL request so that in all posts of the `post_content` links of the type:

`http://example.com/component/tags/tag/15-text.html`

Replace with links of the type:

`http://example.com/tag/text.html`

That is, I need to replace all the characters that are between '`example.com/`' and '`text.html`', with '`tag/`'
taking into account the fact that the number in the link can be any one-, two- or three-digit (from 1 to 999 ).

If the wildcard '`%`' could be used in the `REPLACE` function, then the request could look something like this:

`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'component/tags/tag/%-', 'tag/');`

Unfortunately, this does not work. I have no experience with databases,
but it seems to me that the desired request can be created using `SUBSTRING_INDEX`,
but I didn't succeed in doing it myself. I would be grateful for any help.

**More examples:**

There are -> should be

```
http://example.com/component/tags/tag/15-text.html  ->  http://example.com/tag/text.html

http://example.com/component/tags/tag/1-sometext.html  ->  http://example.com/tag/sometext.html

http://example.com/component/tags/tag/2-anothertext.html  ->  http://example.com/tag/anothertext.html
```

and so on

```
http://example.com/component/tags/tag/999-moreanothertext.html  ->  http://example.com/tag/moreanothertext.html
```

What exactly needs to be done: to remove from these links part `Component/Tags/Tag/Somenumber-`,
Where is `Somenumber` is only Placeholder (Variable),

but everything else does not need to be changed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql). “If the wildcard '%' could be used in the REPLACE function” Is it? I don't think it works with `REPLACE`. It would be match with every text so it would remove the text between 2 links, for example.

Comment: What version of mysql are you using? You verified `post_content` is plain text and not serialized already?

Comment: @user3783243:
MySQL version 5.7, text not serialized

Comment: Is `tag` just placeholder text in your example, and that could be variable like `example.com/thing1/text.html` and `example.com/anotherthing/text.html`?

Comment: @woundedstevenjones:
`tag` - not a placeholder (variable).
In fact, the variable in my example is only the number, namely `15`

Comment: every URL has `-text.html` at the end? Or is that part variable too? Could you provide a few different example URLs in your question for more clarity of what you're looking for? Is `http://example.com/component/tags/tag/16-another.html` a valid URL that should rewrite to `http://example.com/tag/another.html`?

Comment: In 5.7 this would be a large task. I would pull data out via PHP, update in PHP, and then update db. Can be done in MySQL with a lot of `substr` and `locate` calls. (also presumes that the link would only ever occur once per record in `post_content`)

Comment: @woundedstevenjones:
probably I made the question not quite clear... I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done via straightforward string replacement methods - `CONCAT`, `SUBSTRING`, `LOCATE`, `REPLACE`. The first 3 queries show the step-by-step logic, while query #4 puts it all together.

*These queries assume `http://example.com/component/tags/tag/` is the same for all URLs. If that's not the case, you could use similar logic to detect the position of `/tag/` and use `SUBSTRING` from there.*

The final query to actually update the table (query #6; note that duplicate URLs might exist after this and can be detected ahead of time with query #5 below):

```
UPDATE
  test
SET
  url = CONCAT(
    'http://example.com/tag/',
    SUBSTRING(
      REPLACE(
        url,
        'http://example.com/component/tags/tag/',
        ''
      ),
      LOCATE(
        '-',
        REPLACE(
          url,
          'http://example.com/component/tags/tag/',
          ''
        )
      ) + 1
    )
  );
```

---

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  url TEXT
);
INSERT INTO test (id, url) VALUES (1, 'http://example.com/component/tags/tag/15-thing.html');
INSERT INTO test (id, url) VALUES (2, 'http://example.com/component/tags/tag/16-another.html');
INSERT INTO test (id, url) VALUES (3, 'http://example.com/component/tags/tag/9999-texttext.html');
INSERT INTO test (id, url) VALUES (4, 'http://example.com/component/tags/tag/9999-more-and-more-and-more-and-more-text.html');
INSERT INTO test (id, url) VALUES (5, 'http://example.com/component/tags/tag/6534562-thing.html');
INSERT INTO test (id, url) VALUES (6, 'http://example.com/component/tags/tag/0-thing.html');
INSERT INTO test (id, url) VALUES (7, 'http://example.com/component/tags/tag/1-sometext.html');
INSERT INTO test (id, url) VALUES (8, 'http://example.com/component/tags/tag/2-anothertext.html');
INSERT INTO test (id, url) VALUES (9, 'http://example.com/component/tags/tag/999-moreanothertext.html');
```

---

**Query #1 - remove the known/standard text before the filename (e.g. 15-thing.html)**

```
SELECT
  REPLACE(
    url,
    'http://example.com/component/tags/tag/',
    ''
  ) as variable_text
FROM test;
```

| variable_text |
| --- |
| 15-thing.html |
| 16-another.html |
| 9999-texttext.html |
| 9999-more-and-more-and-more-and-more-text.html |
| 6534562-thing.html |
| 0-thing.html |
| 1-sometext.html |
| 2-anothertext.html |
| 999-moreanothertext.html |

---

**Query #2 - find the index of - in the remaining string (e.g. 3)**

```
SELECT
  LOCATE(
    '-',
    REPLACE(
      url,
      'http://example.com/component/tags/tag/',
      ''
    )
  ) as hyphen_index
FROM test;
```

| hyphen_index |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 3 |
| 5 |
| 5 |
| 8 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 4 |

---

**Query #3 - remove everything after that index (e.g. thing.html)**

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(
    REPLACE(
      url,
      'http://example.com/component/tags/tag/',
      ''
    ),
    LOCATE(
      '-',
      REPLACE(
        url,
        'http://example.com/component/tags/tag/',
        ''
      )
    ) + 1
  ) as filename
FROM test;
```

| filename |
| --- |
| thing.html |
| another.html |
| texttext.html |
| more-and-more-and-more-and-more-text.html |
| thing.html |
| thing.html |
| sometext.html |
| anothertext.html |
| moreanothertext.html |

---

**Query #4 - construct the full URL (e.g. http://example.com/tag/thing.html)**

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    'http://example.com/tag/',
    SUBSTRING(
      REPLACE(
        url,
        'http://example.com/component/tags/tag/',
        ''
      ),
      LOCATE(
        '-',
        REPLACE(
          url,
          'http://example.com/component/tags/tag/',
          ''
        )
      ) + 1
    )
  ) as new_url
FROM test;
```

| new_url |
| --- |
| http://example.com/tag/thing.html |
| http://example.com/tag/another.html |
| http://example.com/tag/texttext.html |
| http://example.com/tag/more-and-more-and-more-and-more-text.html |
| http://example.com/tag/thing.html |
| http://example.com/tag/thing.html |
| http://example.com/tag/sometext.html |
| http://example.com/tag/anothertext.html |
| http://example.com/tag/moreanothertext.html |

---

**Query #5 - detect duplicates ahead of actually updating the table**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) as duplicate_ids, new_url FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    CONCAT(
      'http://example.com/tag/',
      SUBSTRING(
        REPLACE(
          url,
          'http://example.com/component/tags/tag/',
          ''
        ),
        LOCATE(
          '-',
          REPLACE(
            url,
            'http://example.com/component/tags/tag/',
            ''
          )
        ) + 1
      )
    ) as new_url
  FROM test) as new_urls
GROUP BY new_url
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

| duplicate_ids | new_url |
| --- | --- |
| 1,5,6 | http://example.com/tag/thing.html |

---

**Query #6 - actually update the table**

```
UPDATE
  test
SET
  url = CONCAT(
    'http://example.com/tag/',
    SUBSTRING(
      REPLACE(
        url,
        'http://example.com/component/tags/tag/',
        ''
      ),
      LOCATE(
        '-',
        REPLACE(
          url,
          'http://example.com/component/tags/tag/',
          ''
        )
      ) + 1
    )
  );
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #7 - view the new URLs**

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id | url |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | http://example.com/tag/thing.html |
| 2 | http://example.com/tag/another.html |
| 3 | http://example.com/tag/texttext.html |
| 4 | http://example.com/tag/more-and-more-and-more-and-more-text.html |
| 5 | http://example.com/tag/thing.html |
| 6 | http://example.com/tag/thing.html |
| 7 | http://example.com/tag/sometext.html |
| 8 | http://example.com/tag/anothertext.html |
| 9 | http://example.com/tag/moreanothertext.html |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3zg2r8cpMPNrufF1JUwkUH/3)

Comment: probably I made the question not quite clear
sorry, it's my first question here.
The column has many different links like
`http://example.com/component/tags/tag/somenumber-sometext.html`

What exactly needs to be done: to remove from these links part `Component/Tags/Tag/Somenumber-`,
Where is `Somenumber` is Placeholder (Variable),
but everything else does not need to be touched. 
I edited the question, added more examples. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Using specific examples from my posted answer, which part of this is not working correctly? `http://example.com/component/tags/tag/15-thing.html` becomes `http://example.com/tag/thing.html`, and `http://example.com/component/tags/tag/9999-texttext.html` becomes `http://example.com/tag/texttext.html`. Edit: I added the examples from your question, and this seems to work exactly as described. If that's not the case, please clarify what isn't working.

Comment: Your code works, but not in my case.
Probably because the post_content column contains HTML (WordPress blog posts)
 in which there are text and different links, and not just links.
 It's my fault.
I'm really very sorry.
Had to edit the question again.

Comment: Please include specific examples of what the database contains. Each edit seems to be adding complexity which might be easiesr in a PHP script instead of a MySQL query, but without the full details and specific examples we can't suggest specific solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, 'example.com/', 1), -- Extract the part before 'example.com/'
    'example.com/tag/',                             -- Append the new base URL
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, 'example.com/', -1), '-text.html', 1), -- Extract the number between 'example.com/' and '-text.html'
    '-text.html',                                   -- Append the constant '-text.html'
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, '-text.html', -1) -- Extract the part after '-text.html'
)
WHERE post_content LIKE '%example.com/component/tags/tag/%-text.html%';
```

With the examples given:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, 'example.com/', 1), -- Extract the part before 'example.com/'
    'example.com/tag/',                             -- Append the new base URL
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(post_content, 'example.com/component/tags/tag/[0-9]{1,3}-([^"]+).html'),
        'example.com/component/tags/tag/[0-9]{1,3}-',
        ''
    )
)
WHERE post_content REGEXP 'example.com/component/tags/tag/[0-9]{1,3}-([^"]+).html';
```

Comment: Their question wasn't clear initially, but `-text` is also variable. The filename could be `15-text.html` or `999-another-one.html`.

Comment: @matt:
Sorry, I was too inattentive.
Had to edit the question several times.

REGEXP_REPLACE function was released in version 8.0.4.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need not just a replace, but a replace with regexp. Look at the request below.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('http://example.com/component/tags/tag/15-text.html', 'http://([^/]+)[^-]+-(text\.html)', 'http://$1/tags/$2');
```

Comment: This doesn't exist in mysql 5.7.

Comment: @user3783243:Thanks a lot for the reply,
But my question was not entirely clear, probably.
I edited it.